# how can I pass the struct array of struct tracker defined below when calling master_Level() function

Tags: c++, struct

Getting the error in part 1:

> `conflicting types for 'master_level' and threadcount not declared`

how can I pass the struct array correctly in the both main function and recursively calling inside `master_level()` function?

```
 struct tracker{
    struct node* head;
    int index;
} typedef tracker;

int main(){
...
    int level =2;
    int idx  = 1 ;
    threadCount =10;                          
    tracker * track[threadCount];
    master_Level(head,level, idx,track);
...

}


void master_Level(node* root,int level, int idx,  tracker track[threadcount] ){                                             
//part 1
    if (root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    if (level == 1){
         track[idx]->index= idx;
         track[idx]->head = root;
         idx+=1;
    }
    if (level > 1)
    {
         master_Level(root->left, level-1, idx, track);
         master_Level(root->right, level-1,idx, track);
  return NULL;      
  }
}
```

Comment: The errors seem to be self explanatory ...  but without [MCVE] we can not duplicate.   1) In function master_Level, where is threadcount defined?   (scope prevents access to auto var of main.)   2) parameter tracker (in main) is a pointer, but the function parameter track[] is not.

Comment: Could we get a [mcve] please?

Comment: Try std::vector instead raw array.

Comment: got it, thanks guys